# How to read a file via https - all authentication methods (Java)

Tags: java, https

We need to read a file via http(s) that can require authentication via different protocols. I think we need to handle:

- Basic
- Digest
- Windows (I think this is the same as NTLM?)
- SharePoint (via FBA)
- Claims Based authentication for OData access of SharePoint & MS Dynamics.
- Numerous systems that provide token(s) on login that must be placed in the header of each read.

Is there a single way to do this in Java 6 and/or an Apache library that covers all these cases? And if not, I know how to do Basic, Digest, & header injections, but is there anything showing how to do this for Windows, SharePoint FBA, & CBA?

And is there any commonly used protocol not in my list above? This is read only so no need for WEBDAV.

As to why such an all-encompassing need, this is for a commercial library we ship. I have no idea what our customers will face and so I want to try and cover any possibility.

thanks - dave

Comment: See `java.net.Authenticator`.

Comment: @EJP - doesn't this class prompt the user for the required info? We're generally used on a server where it's running 10,000 reports and there's no UI.

Comment: You don't read _files_ via https. You read HTTP resources. They have no connection to files unless the server happens to make one. Perhaps reading the documentation of the Apache HTTP Components would help you?

Comment: @bmargulies I mean a url like http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml - yes it's a resource but the end result is I'm getting a file.

Comment: HTTP authentication is all supported, primitively, by the builtin HTTPUrlConnection. https://hc.apache.org/ provides a vast library of helpers to assist you in dealing with all the various cases. And no, Authenticator doesn't prompt. It's a code interface.

Comment: For the more obscure cases you cite, I think you're mixing things up. If the server supports HTTP, it will authenticate using HTTP authentication mechanisms. If you are concerned with protocols other than HTTP, well, we're back to your other question where I left an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an 'answer', sort of.

Before addressing the question as you wrote it, I want to throw a challenge back at you: Why does your library need to take responsibility for opening remote resources? Most library APIs are written to accept input as `InputStream` or `Path`, and leave it to the application that calls them to work out how to get access (in the former case) to the particular resource of interest, whether local, remote, or invented on the fly.

Further, your restriction to Java 1.6, now long unsupported and mostly considered obsolete, will severely constrain your ability to find open source assistance in offering broader functionality that 'you can be called with an `InputStream`'.

However, having written that, there is a big difference between resources available via HTTP/HTTPS and resources available via other protocols. Java intrinsically supports HTTP, and libraries such as hc.apache.org provide broad assistance with some of the more annoying details (though, again, there hasn't been a 1.6 compatible release of that for some time).

If you feel the need to support protocols beyond HTTP, you are in a much more difficult landscape. In the mostly-linux ecosystem, the usual next thing is SSH protocol, for which there are good open source alternatives. For more-or-less proprietary protocols such as CIFS (Windows shares), let alone the really Microsoft-specific items, Google will give you all the answers there are, which is why questions that 'ask for an off-site resource or library' are officially off-topic here. You're perhaps better off requiring your customers to enable HTTP access to the resources.

Comment: Good questions in your challenge. 1) for a datasource or template we request a stream. But in a template there can be an import tag that provides a url from which we pull data. No way to get a stream there. 2) Java 1.6 is still supported by Oracle and therefore, as a library, we have to make that our LCD.

Comment: Java 1.6 is only supported for people who pay a mountain of extra money. Anyway, if it's always _a URL_, then the http library is all you need, unless Microsoft has really layered strange proprietary authentication onto HTTP.